# How to clear text input and re focus in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In my code I want to make disable the button if text input field is empty. It was working fine. But when I add the code to clear and re focus the input box it makes the button enabled and this allows the user to create empty divs by clicking the button. Here I am attaching my whole JavaScript code, please someone help me with this to make this work as I want.

**custom_script.js**

```
const subBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
const inptTxt = document.getElementById("text");
const contDiv = document.getElementById("container");

//check input box is empty or not and enable Colorize button
subBtn.disabled = true

inptTxt.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    const value = inptTxt.value.trim()

    if (value) {
        inptTxt.dataset.state = 'valid'
        subBtn.disabled = false
    } else {
        inptTxt.dataset.state = 'invalid'
        subBtn.disabled = true
    }
})

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

subBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){

    xhttp.onload=function() {
        var crd = document.createElement("div");
        var div = contDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var crdCount = div.length;
        crd.setAttribute("id", "card" + crdCount);
        crd.innerHTML = inptTxt.value;

        //change html title with input text
        document.title = inptTxt.value;

        contDiv .appendChild(crd);
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).style.background = JSON.parse(this.responseText).color;  

        //getting inverse value of hex color
        const inv = (hex) => '#' + hex.match(/[a-f0-9]{2}/ig).map(e => (255 - parseInt(e, 16) | 0).toString(16).replace(/^([a-f0-9])$/, '0$1')).join('')
        const invert = () =>
        document.querySelectorAll('circle')
        .forEach(c => 
        (hex = c.getAttribute('fill')) && 
        c.setAttribute('fill', inv(hex))
        )
        var invColor = inv(JSON.parse(this.responseText).color);

        //setting the inverse value to card text
        var crdText = document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML;
        var setColor = "<span style='color:" + invColor + "'>" + crdText + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML = setColor;

        //clear input and refocus
        inptTxt.value = "";
        inptTxt.focus();
        inptTxt.select();
    };

    xhttp.onerror=function() {
        var crd = document.createElement("div");
        var div = contDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var crdCount = div.length;
        crd.setAttribute("id", "card" + crdCount);
        crd.innerHTML = inptTxt.value;

        //change html title with input text
        document.title = inptTxt.value;

        contDiv .appendChild(crd);
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).style.background = "#6d4298";  

        var crdText = document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML;
        var setColor = "<span style='color:#ffffff'>" + crdText + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML = setColor;
    };

    xhttp.open("GET","http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor");
    xhttp.send(); 

})

//submit quote using Enter key
inptTxt.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    subBtn.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add minimal and relevant code only, and not the whole JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because setting the `value` of an `input` via javascript doesn't trigger it's `input` event.

You need to trigger its event manually after you set its value.

Here's the solution, notice the comments marked with `FIX`:

```js
const subBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
const inptTxt = document.getElementById("text");
const contDiv = document.getElementById("container");

//check input box is empty or not and enable Colorize button
subBtn.disabled = true

// FIX: make a dedicated function for validation
function validateInput() {
    const value = inptTxt.value.trim()

    if (value) {
        inptTxt.dataset.state = 'valid'
        subBtn.disabled = false
    } else {
        inptTxt.dataset.state = 'invalid'
        subBtn.disabled = true
    }
}

// FIX: call the validation function when the input is changed
inptTxt.addEventListener('input', validateInput);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

subBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {

    xhttp.onload = function () {
        var crd = document.createElement("div");
        var div = contDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var crdCount = div.length;
        crd.setAttribute("id", "card" + crdCount);
        crd.innerHTML = inptTxt.value;

        //change html title with input text
        document.title = inptTxt.value;

        contDiv.appendChild(crd);
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).style.background = JSON.parse(this.responseText).color;

        //getting inverse value of hex color
        const inv = (hex) => '#' + hex.match(/[a-f0-9]{2}/ig).map(e => (255 - parseInt(e, 16) | 0).toString(16).replace(/^([a-f0-9])$/, '0$1')).join('')
        const invert = () =>
            document.querySelectorAll('circle')
                .forEach(c =>
                    (hex = c.getAttribute('fill')) &&
                    c.setAttribute('fill', inv(hex))
                )
        var invColor = inv(JSON.parse(this.responseText).color);

        //setting the inverse value to card text
        var crdText = document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML;
        var setColor = "<span style='color:" + invColor + "'>" + crdText + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML = setColor;

        //clear input and refocus
        inptTxt.value = "";
        inptTxt.focus();
        inptTxt.select();
        // FIX: call the validation function when the input is cleared
        validateInput();
    };

    xhttp.onerror = function () {
        var crd = document.createElement("div");
        var div = contDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var crdCount = div.length;
        crd.setAttribute("id", "card" + crdCount);
        crd.innerHTML = inptTxt.value;

        //change html title with input text
        document.title = inptTxt.value;

        contDiv.appendChild(crd);
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).style.background = "#6d4298";

        var crdText = document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML;
        var setColor = "<span style='color:#ffffff'>" + crdText + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("card" + crdCount).innerHTML = setColor;
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor");
    xhttp.send();

})

//submit quote using Enter key
inptTxt.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        subBtn.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works as expected! Thank you @Hao Wu for your clear answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple snippet of input and button.

I used the `onInput` event to detect whenever the input is changing. When it does, I just set the `disable` property of the button to be the answer of whether the input is empty or not.

Note that I'm initializing the button with `disabled` attribute because at the start it should be disabled.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let input = document.getElementById('input');

function doSomething() {
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
  inputHasChanged();
}

function inputHasChanged() {
  button.disabled = input.value === '';
}
```

```html
<button disabled id="button" onclick="doSomething()">click</button>
<input id="input" type="text" onInput="inputHasChanged()">
```